# incomplete http response body when printing in flutter

Tags: xml, http, dart, flutter

I'm trying to fetch xml feed using flutter http plugin. The length of body of response that http.get returns is correct. But when I try to pars it using xml plugin, the parsed result is not complete.

Also, when I print the body of the response, the printed values are far less than expected.

```dart
  http.get(url).then((res) {
    print(res.body.length);
    var document = xml.parse(res.body);
    document.children.forEach((xmlNode) {
      print(xmlNode.text);
     });
  });
```

It seems to be a buffering overflow problem...or because I'm using UI thread for the parsing process??

Comment: It seems that I should use webfeed 0.4.2

Comment: Actually you should use ```debugPrint``` instead of ```print``` (you'll have to import it from one of flutter packages)